# Analytic class number formula for orders

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

In the article "The analytic class number formula for orders in products of number fields" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.04564.pdf), it is shown that the analytic class number formula holds for arbitrary orders in a number fields.

The proof goes through some abstract algebra, but I was wondering if one could not just modify the typical proof for the ring of integers, as found in Borevich and Shafarevich's "Number Theory" for example.

This seems to be possible, but I have not found any litterature doing it in this way, so I was wondering if I have overlooked something?